# Combining jQuery file upload with form to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have a form that stores text fields to a database. For image upload, I am using Blueimp jQuery File upload.

I'm looking for a good way of combining these, so I can store the image URL to a field in my database.

The jquery variable file.url gives me the URL of the uploaded file (after renaming if another image has same name as uploaded file.

```
var link = $('<a>')
.attr('target', '_blank')
.prop('href', file.url);
console.log(file.url); // gives: http://localhost/uploads/image.jpg
```

Can I somehow send this URL to a hidden input field in my form? I'm aware that the image has to be uploaded before I submit form, otherwise the jQuery variable is empty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this in steps. First you ask the main info and then you ask the user for the picture.

If you can't (or simply don't want it to be this way) the easiest way is to set a hidden field with this value.

As an alternative, you can upload this file to a temporary folder or with a specific name that you can associate to the data you are about to send, like an ID or session ID of the user + some unique identifier.

After you send the image via the plugin you will not need to send the image url with the form data, since you will know where it will be and can rename, move and build the url before saving the data to the database.